# Difference between the return value of thrd_join and its res parameter?

Tags: c, c11

I have a hard time understanding the usage of thrd_join. Its declaration is this:

```
int thrd_join( thrd_t thr, int *res );
```

The section reads:

> If **res** is not a null pointer, the result code of the thread is put to the location pointed to by **res**

So I take it that the variable **res** contains the return code of the thread to be joined. What is the return value of **thrd_join()** used for then? Is that a code signifying that the join will be successful and that I can take contents of **res** seriously?

Do I have that right?

Comment: Where did you get this function from? If it has a documentation, it should tell what return value is.

Comment: *"**[Return value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_join)**
`thrd_success` if successful, `thrd_error` otherwise."*

Comment: So if I get `thrd_error`, the joining failed and `res` doesn't contain a valid value. If I get `thrd_success`, joining went OK and `res` contains the return value. Right?

Comment: What could be the alternative behavior?

Comment: Well I wasn't given a list of the possible things that might go wrong when joining a thread. I thought that either the thread exits successfully, or not. Either way, the join happens. Perhaps I'm mistaken in thinking that - that is a source of confusion for me.

Comment: Since, as you say, the return code is not informative, you cannot distinguish the errors, so you cannot trust the `res` value in case of *any* error.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sounds perfectly reasonable. I guess I just got tangled up in it so badly that I needed an external point of view. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread is [started](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_create) with a function of `thrd_start_t` which is typedef for `int(*)(void*)`(cf. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)), i.e. it takes a `void *`, and returns an `int`. The return value of this function is stored to the location pointed to by `res`. The return code of the call to[`thrd_join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_join) itself is its return value.

Comment: While not helpful to me personally, it is a good summary and a good fit for an accepted answer.

Comment: If you can detail, what else you would need to know, I try to update my answer. I could add a pointer to the standard (C11 draft N1570 section 7.26.5.6), but I guess that is obvious.

Answer (score -2):

That function is like many many functions in C where the function returns an "error code" signifying error or success and the function has an out parameter which holds the real output.

In some cases you can ignore those error codes , for example `printf` returns `int` too yet we mostly don't check for its return type.

When the error case has good probability it's good to check for errors then.

Notice that in languages like `java` or `C#` the function returns the real output and `Exceptions` are the way to represent possible errors.

Comment: That's too generic to be of any value. I obviously understand what return codes are for, but this specific case seemed different to me.

Comment: @PavelMatuska Not really different. If you use `scanf("%d", &number)`, you should check  it's return value. And if it is not `1` you can't trust the value of `number`. Dunno why it is downvoted badly. Probably because of "you can ignore those error codes".

Comment: @PavelMatuska as EugeneSh said, I didn't see your case very different